# Lost posix utilities on Mac OSX, any ideas on debugging?

Tags: bash, shell, posix

Suddenly I lost almost everything on the command line. I can do `cd`, `exit` and `pwd`...nothing else that I tried...no `ls`, no `vi`...nothing....

I do have an open terminal that's still working, but no new ones...as soon as I exit out of the current session, I'm screwed...

I was about to say I'm baffled...but I just noticed that now /etc is symlinked to /etc/private. Don't remember that being the case before...

I recently upgraded to Snow Leopard...but I've rebooted since with no problems... No clue when this came about...

Any ideas on debugging it?

Comment: `/etc -> private/etc` is normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your `PATH` environment variable may be messed up.  You may have messed it up in a `.profile`, `.bashrc`, `.tcshrc`, `.login` or similar shell startup file.  Check using:

```
echo $PATH
```

Then (assuming you are using a bash shell) try setting it with:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
```

You could also try typing commands using the full path, e.g. `/bin/ls`.  If you want to make sure that your commands are still there you should be able to use `echo /bin/* /usr/bin/*`.

`/etc` has always been a symbolic link to `private/etc` on Mac OS X.

Comment: Thank you! That highlighted the issue immediately. I added something to the path which overwrote it rather than appending it. Whew!!

Answer (score 1):

Start with `echo $PATH` to see what's there.  Mine contains:

```
/Users/jleffler/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:.
```

On my machine, /etc is a symlink to /private/etc, and /tmp is a symlink to /private/tmp (and isn't accessible to other user IDs).

If that isn't the problem, check whether /usr/bin and /bin are available (they are not symlinked on my machine).